# 'Enable SSL' not visible in ASP.Net Core project properties

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/index), I'm trying to set up social logins for my ASP.NET web application. The option `enable SSL`, however, is not visible in my project properties. Ignoring that aspect of the tutorial results in a bunch of errors, so that's not really an option.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 RC.

Image:

[image: Visual Studio Project Properties]

Comment: Is that a console app project?  `Launch` should be set to `IISExpress` as well...What are your options for `Launch` drop down?

Comment: ASP.NET Core is fully decoupled from web servers, so it won't know whether HTTPS is used or not. That's why I guess the option is removed. You can go directly to IIS Express configuration file to set SSL.

Comment: @Mike_G It's an ASP.Net Core Web Application, running from Visual Studio rather than the command line. The options under `Launch` are `Executable` (which, when selected, shows a `Executable path` field) and `Project`.

Comment: @LexLi Which configuration file is that?

Comment: In .vs hidden folder under the solution folder.

Comment: @LexLi I tried that (`<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44302:localhost" />`, but the browser refuses to connect to the specified port.